# Ellptic Differential Operator is not Fredholm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a manifold either with boundary $Y$ or cylindrical end $[0,\infty)\times Y$, and $D$ be a Dirac type operator.

**Q**: Is this always true that $D$ is a Fredholm operator,  for either case on $X$?

Answer (score 1):

[Callias' paper from '78 (especially Theorem 1. [Seeley's Theorem])](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103904395) answers your question for the non-compact, w/o boundary case (well, technically he does this for $\mathbb{R}^n$ only, but if you google, say "Callias type theorems", you'll find generalizations for manifolds with cylindrical ends).

In the case of manifolds with boundary it's even less obvious what the Hilbert spaces are (that is, what the boundary conditions are), but the answer is still ``it depends'', and I cannot really give you a better one right now.